# Is it possible to get the source of the document?

Tags: solr

I'm implementing my very first Solr based search application. The application is currently using a database server and local files (txt, xml) as data sources.

I was wondering if it's possible to display the source of a document on display. Is it possible to say for example: Result1 from 1.txt, Result2 from database ... etc ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create extra field, for example *source*, which could hold that information. This field can be populated straight from data importer making it pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'm completely new to Solr, could you point me out to some sources about the data importer or something related to my question?

Comment: For the core of data importer head to official wiki [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler). This will get you started. For example, aside from usual `SELECT column1, column2...` you could use `SELECT column1, column2, 'database' as source...`. You can try similar trick with URLDataSource by adding 'source' column and playing with xpath.